# Play Scala and thread safety

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework

The project is written using `Play framework` and `Scala` language.
I have implemented `compile time dependency`.
I have followed this example from Play:

https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-compile-di-example

Looking at the `MyApplicationLoader.scala`:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.routing.Router

class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  private var components: MyComponents = _

  def load(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Application = {
    components = new MyComponents(context)
    components.application
  }
}

class MyComponents(context: ApplicationLoader.Context) 
  extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with play.filters.HttpFiltersComponents
  with _root_.controllers.AssetsComponents {

  lazy val homeController = new _root_.controllers.HomeController(controllerComponents)

  lazy val router: Router = new _root_.router.Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController, assets)
}
```

and the following line of code:

```
 lazy val homeController = new _root_.controllers.HomeController(controllerComponents)
```

my understanding is that there is only one instance of `HomeController` created the first time `HomeController` is called.
And that instance lives as long as the application lives. Are these statements correct?

The `HomeController` in my application looks like that:

```
class HomeController{

   val request = // some code here

   val workflowExecutionResult = Workflow.execute(request)

}
```

So `Workflow` is of type `object` and not `class`.

The `Workflow` looks like that:

```
object Workflow {
  def execute(request: Request) = {

    val retrieveCustomersResult = RetrieveCustomers.retrieve() 
    // some code here

    val createRequestResult = CreateRequest.create(request)
    // some code here

    workflowExecutionResult
  }
}
```

So `Workflow` calls a few domain services and each domain service is of type `object` and not `class`.
All values inside the domain services are immutable, I am using `val`s everywhere.

Is this enough to ensure thread safety?

I am asking as I'm used to writing `C# Web APIs` where a `HomeController` would look like that:

```
class HomeControllerInSeeSharpProject{

    // some code here

    var request = new Request() // more code here
    var workflow = new WorkflowInSeeSharpProject()
    var workflowExecutionResult = workflow.execute(request)
}
```

and a `Workflow` would look like that:

```
public class WorkflowInSeeSharpProject {

  public execute(Request request) {

      var retrieveCustomers = new RetrieveCustomers()
      var retrieveCustomersResult = retrieveCustomers.retrieve()

      // some code here
      var createRequest = new CreateRequest()
      var createRequestResult = createRequest.create(request)

      // some code here
      return workflowExecutionResult
  }
}
```

So in a C# project every time a `HomeControllerInSeeSharpProject` is called a new instance of `WorkflowInSeeSharpProject` is created and all the domain services
are also newed-up and then I can be sure that state cannot be shared between separate threads. So I am afraid that because my `Scala` `Workflow`
and domain services are of type `object` and not `class` that there could be a situation where two requests are sent into the `HomeController`
and state is shared between those two threads.

Can this be the case? Is my application not thread safe?

I have read that `object`s in Scala are not thread safe since there is only single instance of them. However I have also read that although
they are not thread safe using `val`s will make the application thread safe...

Or maybe `Play` itself has a way to deal with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your are using compile time dependency injection, you control the number of instances created, and in your case `HomeController` is created only once. As requests come in, this single instance will be shared between threads so indeed you have to make sure it is thread-safe. All the dependencies of `HomeController` will also need to be thread-safe, thus `object Workflow` has to be thread-safe. Currently, `Workflow` is not publicly exposing any shared state, so it is thread-safe. In general, `val` definitions within `object` are [thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047657/val-at-object-level-and-thread-safety-in-scala#answer-23048497).

In effect `HomeController` is behaving like a singleton and avoiding singletons could be safer. For example, by default Play Framework uses [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) dependency injection which creates a new controller instance per request as long as it is not a `@Singleton`. One motivation is there is less state to worry about regarding concurrency protection as suggested by [Nio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643080/why-use-singletone-controllers-in-play-2-5#answer-40653182):

> In general, it is probably best to not use @Singleton unless you have
>   a fair understanding of immutability and thread-safety. If you think
>   you have a use case for Singleton though just make sure you are
>   protecting any shared state.