# Play Framework without dependency injection?

Tags: scala, playframework

Without going into why, say someone wanted an old-fashioned Play Framework web service and did not want to use dependency injection nor rely on Google's Guice. Is it still possible in Play 2.8.x?

The [api documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/scala/play/api/mvc/index.html) along with the current Play examples recommend this as a "typical" HomeController.scala:

```
package controllers
import javax.inject._
import play.api.mvc._
class HomeController @Inject() (val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {
  def index = Action {
    Ok("It works!")
  }
}
```

My desired code is the same, but without @Inject() (similar to when I last used Play 2.4.0 in 2016)? Back in the day my code looked like this:

```
package controllers
import play.api.mvc.{Action, AnyContent, Controller}
object TestController {
  def index:Action[AnyContent] = Action {
    Ok("It used to work.")
  }
}
```

Console:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Volumes/.../play-scala-seed/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] p.a.h.DefaultHttpErrorHandler - 

! @7ef69nl6l - Internal server error, for (GET) [/test/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.TestController. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at controllers.TestController.class(TestController.scala:3)
  while locating controllers.TestController
    for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:33)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:137):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)

1 error]
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.reload(DevServerStart.scala:210)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.get(DevServerStart.scala:141)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.handleRequest(AkkaHttpServer.scala:296)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$createServerBinding$1(AkkaHttpServer.scala:186)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.MapAsync$$anon$30.onPush(Ops.scala:1261)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processPush(GraphInterpreter.scala:541)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:423)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:624)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:501)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:599)
Caused by: com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Could not find a suitable constructor in controllers.TestController. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at controllers.TestController.class(TestController.scala:3)
  while locating controllers.TestController
    for the 4th parameter of router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:33)
  at play.api.inject.RoutesProvider$.bindingsFromConfiguration(BuiltinModule.scala:137):
Binding(class router.Routes to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$4)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:159)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:78)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:200)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:155)
    at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anon$1.$anonfun$reload$3(DevServerStart.scala:189)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
```

Is there a simple fix to stay old school--without going [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301389/why-does-one-use-dependency-injection/14301496#14301496)?

I acknowledge but don't totally understand https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24. I assume my problem has to do with static routing having been removed in [2.7](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaRouting#Dependency-Injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reputation doesn't allow me to comment to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59725511/1640281) by [Mario Galic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5205022/mario-galic), but you can easily modify his example by using the "right" (non-test) `controllerComponents` that are provided by `BuiltInComponentsFromContext`.

The whole example would look like

```scala
class HomeController(override protected val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents)
  extends BaseController {
  def index = Action { Ok("It works!") }
}

class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Application = {
    new BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
      lazy val homeController = HomeController(controllerComponents)
      override lazy val router: Router = Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController)
    }.application
  }
}
```

Comment: is there an equivalent example in java?

Comment: I couldn't fit my reply in a comment and not sure tagging people in other answers works, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60345559/1640281 @kujosHeist .

Comment: Thanks. I gave your rep a boost and aknowledge and thank @Mario Galic as well. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @TomasMilata My understanding was OP did not want to inject anything in controllers, thus I provided empty constructor to `HomeController` and did not inject `CCs`. Hence the contrived `stubControllerComponents` example. Indeed your answer is the correct way to do it, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

To answer comment by @kujosHeist about an equivalent example in Java. This seems to work for me (Following the [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCompileTimeDependencyInjection)):

```java
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        return ok("It works!");
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyApplicationLoader implements ApplicationLoader {

    @Override
    public Application load(Context context) {
        return new MyComponents(context).application();
    }
}


class MyComponents extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext implements HttpFiltersComponents, AssetsComponents {

    public MyComponents(ApplicationLoader.Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Router router() {
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        Assets assets = new Assets(scalaHttpErrorHandler(), assetsMetadata());
        return new router.Routes(scalaHttpErrorHandler(), homeController, assets).asJava();
    }

}
```

You might want to define things like e.g. error handlers differently, but this could be roughly the structure.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `StaticRoutesGenerator` has been [removed](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/8049) which is need to have controllers as singleton objects. Perhaps using [compile time dependency injection](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection), with an example [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.8.x/play-scala-compile-di-example), might bring you closer to what you were used to, however `ControllerComponents` will still need to be injected. Technically, it might be possible to do something ill-advised by putting [`play-test`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.play/play-test_2.13/2.8.0) on the `Compile` classpath and make use [`stubControllerComponents`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/ddf3a7ee4285212ec665826ec268ef32b5a76000/testkit/play-test/src/main/scala/play/api/test/Helpers.scala#L640) like so

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
  def index = Action { Ok("It works!") }

  override protected def controllerComponents: ControllerComponents = 
     play.api.test.Helpers.stubControllerComponents()
}
```

and corresponding minimal `ApplicationLoader`

```
class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Application = {
    new BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
      override def httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Nil
      lazy val homeController = new _root_.controllers.HomeController
      lazy val router: Router = new _root_.router.Routes(httpErrorHandler, homeController)
    }.application
  }
}
```

This way `HomeController`, although still a class, is now completely hardwired, and there is only a single instance of it created in `ApplicationLoader`.

Personally, I would advise against such shenanigans, and believe there are good [arguments](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Motivation) why Play moved away from singletons, for example, testability, [thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50619826/5205022), etc.

Comment: Thanks. It's just funny--having skipped forward in time--to hear Play seeming to sing a different tune about the virtues of controllers as objects. I'll probably have to come around.